# What is the maximum integer it is safe to use in a Javascript bitmask flag value?

Tags: javascript, bitmask, bit-masks

This is mostly just a sanity-check.

Mozilla [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Flags_and_bitmasks) that

> The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit
>   integers in two's complement format.

and that

> The numbers -2147483648 and 2147483647 are the minimum and the maximum
>   integers representable through a 32bit signed number.

Since 2147483647 is 0x7FFFFFFF, I believe that 0x40000000 (that is to say, **not** 0x80000000) is the maximum number I can safely use as a javascript flag value. But I'd like to make sure I haven't missed something or that there aren't other gotchas. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value range is a complete 32-bit value, ie. 0 to 0xffffffff (or 2<sup>32</sup>-1). If it will be signed or not depends. If it will be signed initially then this will produce -1:

```js
document.write(0xffffffff>>0);
```

But you can use unsigned values too which means the range is [0, 4294967295]:

```js
document.write(0xffffffff>>>0);
```

The number 0x40000000 is only gonna give you *half* your range (in the negative range, in the positive it would be 0x40000000-1, or 0x3fffffff) so this is not the safe number for a 32-bit signed range.

You safe-range for signed number would be [0x80000000, 0x7fffffff], so the common safe-margin *mask* would be 0x7fffffff, however, you would need to preserve the sign-bit:

```
number = number < 0 ? number & 0xffffffff : 0x7fffffff;
```

And for unsigned your mask would always be 0xffffffff.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think I may have misspoken. I'm asking about the largest safe flag value. So, for example:

var FLAG_A = 0x1;
var FLAG_B = 0x2;
var FLAG_C = 0x4;
var FLAG_MAX = 0x.....?

Are you saying that I can actually use 0x80000000 as a flag? Sorry if I'm a little slow here -- these bitwise transforms always hurt my brain a bit.

Comment: @BrianRak yes, you can use that as a flag (most-significant bit) and for signed values you *have* to use it if you want to detect negative numbers. lol, yeah bits are like splints, small but with the potential to hurt.